# Calculus integration problem. [HW help]

Tags: integration

Can someone please help me solve the following calculus problem for my homework?

[image]

Comment: It is probably just a cute way of saying $\int x^2 dx $ or $\int 2x dx$

Comment: @Prahlad: I’d interpret as $\int x^2\,dx$, but I’d also explain that I was doing so, interpreting juxtaposition as product the product *orange segment* with *orange segment* rather than as *two orange segments*.

Comment: Upvote for pic.

Comment: They look like mandarin orange.

Comment: Have you tried *integration by orange parts*?

Comment: So the answer is the top thirds of three mandarin orange segments plus a coconut?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $x$ be "orange segment".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the symbolism the only possible solutions is$$\int x.x dx=?$$ $$\int x^2dx=\frac{x^3}{3}=\frac{x.x.x}{1+1+1}$$